# How do you turn a local variable into a global variable?

Tags: javascript

var newIp;

```
function getIP(json) {
    document.write("My public IP address is: " + json.ip); //<-- This works properly
    var newIp = json.ip; //<-- Trying to change newIp into a global variable.
    console.log(typeof json.ip); //<-- Returns "string"
  }
  console.log(newIp); //<-- outputs to undefined?? Why??
```

There is also a script that I included to the index.html "src="http://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP" and I do get the local IP address "json.ip" to work properly.

I cannot figure out how to turn the "json.ip" into a global variable to use in other parts of my app. Can someone give me a real example of how to do this?

Comment: `newIp =` - i.e. don't use `var` (or `let` or `const`) - but this smells of not knowing how to handle asynchrony :p

Comment: use this => `window.newIp = json.ip`

Comment: Jaromanda X please explain with a useful example.

Comment: @Cristien If it is indeed to do with asynchronicity, (which is likely) then you should have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

updated

you have this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getIP(json) {
    document.write("My public IP address is: " + json.ip);
    window.newIp = json.ip;
    console.log(typeof json.ip); //<-- Returns "string"
  }
</script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log(newIp);
</script>
```

now you can put this code in a file, lets say **myScript.js**

```
  function getIP(json) {
    document.write("My public IP address is: " + json.ip);
    window.newIp = json.ip;
    console.log(typeof json.ip); //<-- Returns "string"
  }
```

and now you need to include them in your html in this order

```
<script src="./myScript.js"></script> <!--let's say your myscript is lying with html file in same folder-->
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
<script>
  console.log(newIp);
</script>
```

here order of the scrip tag matters brother
so try this and let me know

Comment: I removed the initial var newIp and it throws this error "api.js:20 Uncaught ReferenceError: newIp is not defined" which is the last console.log

Comment: you need to run the function before last console.log

Comment: i have updated the code look again

Comment: Could you please explain how to set "json.ip" as a value in the getIP invocation (instead of a test ip) so I can set it as a variable and use it somewhere else?

Comment: where do you invoke this function in your code? before me giving this code what you were doing with this code ? how did you use it in your code show me that part. what is the value of argument you pass in ?

Comment: I included this to the index.html <script src="http://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>. I am trying to turn the Ip address into a variable so I can use it elsewhere in my application but I cannot figure out how to extract it from my function. json.ip gives me my ip address. I want to turn json.ip into a global variable.

Comment: ok i got it wait for some time i m doing it. wait for some time

Comment: Sorry could not get it to work for me.

Comment: its working. i have successfully tested the code. how you are implementing it ?

Comment: Can you tell me why when I move the function declaration into the JS file it breaks, but when it is is in the HTML file it works? https://codepen.io/ancri-gonzalez-torres/pen/WNQxRPR?editors=0001

Comment: look the updated answer and update your question with the approach you are doing ?  i mean how you are puting them in different file ?

Comment: I'm trying to keep proper separation of concerns. I'm trying to keep my JS in a seperate file. I'd like to keep the index.html clean without many scripts. See what I'm trying to do here. I know it has something to do with the execution order because when I move the function declaration and console.log over to the index.html it works fine. https://codepen.io/CristienL/pen/oNjLaGZ?editors=1111

Comment: if you really like coding using better architecture techniques then you must learn a framework. a lot of work is being handled by them. its seamless to use them. you get package management out of the box. so i recommend you to learn angular. you ll get addicted.

Answer (score 0):

```
var newIp;
function getIP(json) {
    document.write("My public IP address is: " + json.ip); //<-- This works properly
    newIp = json.ip; //<-- Trying to change newIp into a global variable.
    console.log(typeof json.ip); //<-- Returns "string"
}
getIP({ip:"127.0.0.1"});
console.log(newIp);
```

Comment: This is still returning "undefined" on the last console.log.

Comment: you need call `getIP()` before `console.log(newIp)`

Comment: Can you clarify this?

Comment: I fixed code in answer

Answer (score 0):

If you define a variable into a function, you can't access it outside of that function. This variable is scoped into only for that function.

```
function greetings() {
    let name = 'Robin';
    console.log(name); // Robin
}
console.log(name); // undefined
```

So if you want to access that `name` variable outside of `greetings` function, you need to declare it on the same scope. In this case on global scope like that.

```
let name;
function greetings() {
    name = 'Robin';
    console.log(name); // Robin
}
console.log(name); // Robin
```

*OR* if you want to use a variable all over the places of your app, you can define it into window object or declare a global variable like `let DB = {}`. Then declare your variable like that `DB.ip = 'value'`;

So you can get the value of ip all over the places using `DB.ip`. You can do it with window object also.